# Why request work in postman but does not work in curl (C++ libcurl)

Tags: c++, curl

I'm trying download comments from YouTube through private api but for some reason request to api does not work in curl. It should return JSON with information about comments under video but to me it return nothing. Literally nothing. In postman with same parameters and headers all work perfectly. I think that i'm not correctly use curl but i does not know where i wrong.
My downloader code:

```
QMap<QString, QString> commentsChunk = {
        {"Accept", "*/*"},
        {"Host", "www.youtube.com"},
        {"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
        {"Origin", "https://www.youtube.com"},
        {"DNT", "1"},
        {"Pragma", "no-cache"},
        {"Cache-control", "no-cache"},
        {"TE", "Trailers"},
    };
    QString dir = KTools::Options::configPath + "/tmp";
    cc->setErrFile(dir, "errfile.txt");
    cc->currHeaderMode = KTools::Enums::Curl::HeaderMode::None;
    cc->currCookieMode = KTools::Enums::Curl::CookieMode::GetAllTimes;
    cc->cookieFileName = "cookieYoutube.txt";
    cc->cookiePath = KTools::Options::configPath;
    cc->setOptions();
    QByteArray data = cc->request(params.value("url").toString() + "/videos");
    KTools::HtmlAst::Object htmlObj = KTools::HtmlAst::Object();
    htmlObj.makeAst(data);
    QString xsrfToken = QUrl::toPercentEncoding(htmlObj.arrsAndObjs.objects[0].value("XSRF_TOKEN").toString());;
    commentsChunk["X-YouTube-Client-Version"] = htmlObj.arrsAndObjs.objects[0].value("INNERTUBE_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION").toString();
    commentsChunk["X-YouTube-Client-Name"] = htmlObj.arrsAndObjs.objects[0].value("INNERTUBE_CONTEXT_CLIENT_NAME").toVariant().toString();
    QJsonArray videosInfo = htmlObj.arrsAndObjs.objects[3].value("contents").toObject().value("twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer").toObject().value("tabs").toArray()[1].toObject().value("tabRenderer").toObject().value("content").toObject().value("sectionListRenderer").toObject().value("contents").toArray()[0].toObject().value("itemSectionRenderer").toObject().value("contents").toArray()[0].toObject().value("gridRenderer").toObject().value("items").toArray(); // line 45 "items":[...]
    QVector<QString> videosId;
    for (int i = 0; i < videosInfo.size(); i++)
    {
        videosId.append(videosInfo[i].toObject().value("gridVideoRenderer").toObject().value("videoId").toString());
    }

    data = cc->request("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videosId[1]);
    htmlObj = KTools::HtmlAst::Object();
    htmlObj.makeAst(data);
    QJsonArray continuations = htmlObj.arrsAndObjs.objects[5].value("contents").toObject().value("twoColumnWatchNextResults").toObject().value("secondaryResults").toObject().value("secondaryResults").toObject().value("continuations").toArray();
    QVector<QJsonObject> commentsJsons;
    cc->restartSession();
    cc->setRequestType(KTools::Enums::Curl::RequestType::Post);
    cc->currHeaderMode = KTools::Enums::Curl::HeaderMode::Custom;

    QVector<QVector<QVector<QString>>> regexResult;
    KTools::ExForString::executeRegex(data, {{"([^\"]+___________[^\"]+)\",\"[^\"]+\":\"([^\"]+)"}}, regexResult);


    cc->setHeader(commentsChunk);
    cc->setOptions();

    QString tmp = QUrl::toPercentEncoding(regexResult[0][0][1]);
    QString tmp2 = QUrl::toPercentEncoding(regexResult[0][0][2]);
    cc->currPostParam = "session_token=" + xsrfToken;
    data = cc->request("https://www.youtube.com/comment_service_ajax?action_get_comments=1&pbj=1&ctoken=" + tmp + "&continuation=" + tmp + "&itct=" + tmp2);

    KTools::File::writeFile((tmp + "\n" + tmp2 + "\n" + cc->currPostParam).toUtf8(), dir, "requestParams.txt");
    cc->unsetErrFile();
    QString nope;
```

My curl wrapper code: 
Header file: https://pastebin.com/beg1MYgG 
Implementation file: https://pastebin.com/Dv4i823P 

Curl log: https://pastebin.com/xXnsQEqY

Update: Thanks to suggestion in comment i locate my problem. For some reason function std::string::c_str() work incorrectly, in other words gives random characters. How can i fix it?

Comment: Try to compare your requests by hand. *nc -l 8080* will listen on port 8080, you can then test your c++ and postman to see the differencies (cookies, header...)

Comment: @ErwanDaniel What is nc? What i should install on windows for this command?

Comment: Windows provides curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it's just been UB.

```
if (currRequestType == KTools::Enums::Curl::RequestType::Post)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(gCurlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, currPostParam.toStdString().c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(gCurlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, currPostParam.size());
}
```

Curl store not string but reference to string. But temporary string returned bu c_str() destroys in the end of if statement.